# Looking for a way to impliment a pop out read more link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am kind of handcuffed here with a limited spacing of 350px x 160px, my goal is to highlight three main topics from a CMS and have a READ MORE link for each. Achieving this by either a horizontal fly out to the right or to have it pop up like a tooltip that stays up until the user clicks to close.

I am having some issues getting my head around this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated

WDH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [jQuery Read More Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/readmore)

#### [one more article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/02/more-showing-more-hiding)

*Remember* : try with yourself; that is best way of learning

**ALL D BEST**

Comment: Sadly I do not have the space to implement the accordion type script, I am looking for something that spans outside of the box that the main headings are contained. The only thing I can think of right now would be a sort of Lightbox derivative...

Comment: I would like to thank you diEcho, I decided to use a modified version of the jQueryTools "Overlay" yesterday.

Comment: @WebDevHed My pleasure:) accept this  answer; this would be benifitial for me as well as for me

Comment: Done... those other links are informative to say the least.